# order by first then group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables as follows

**questions** (q_id,question,cat_id)

**answers** (a_id,q_id,answer,user_id,rate)

**users** (user_id,username)

Now I want all questions of a particular category and its one answer if exits which has highest rate and username of that person who has answered.

I am using following query to do this but it is not giving me that answer which has highest rate.

```
select c.*,d.username,d.user_id
from users d
join  (
    SELECT b.*,a.question
    FROM `questions` a
    left join answers b
    on a.q_id=b.q_id
    WHERE a.`cat_id` = 8
    group by b.q_id) c
on c.user_id=d.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if try this:

```
SELECT c.*,d.username,d.user_id
FROM users d
JOIN (
    SELECT b.*,a.question
    FROM `questions` a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM answers t1
        JOIN (
            SELECT q_id, max(rate) AS rate FROM answers GROUP BY q_id
        ) t2
        ON t1.q_id = t2.q_id AND t1.rate = t2.rate
    ) b ON a.q_id=b.q_id
    WHERE a.`cat_id` = 8
    GROUP BY b.q_id) c ON c.user_id=d.user_id
```

Cause you have not provided some sample data and desired result, so this may not work as you expected.

***Edited:***

```
SELECT q.*, a.*
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.*, u.user_id, u.username
    FROM answers t1
    INNER JOIN questions t3 ON t1.q_id = t3.q_id AND t3.cat_id = 8
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT q_id, max(rate) AS rate FROM answers GROUP BY q_id
    ) t2
    ON t1.q_id = t2.q_id AND t1.rate = t2.rate
    LEFT JOIN users u ON t1.user_id = u.user_id
    ORDER BY t1.a_id LIMIT 1
) a 
ON q.q_id = a.q_id
WHERE q.cat_id = 8
```

Comment: How is `a` avail outside of the derived?

Comment: yeah working fine thanks

Comment: Oh I see, my eyes are tired, thought it was outside of it. My bad

Comment: sorry bro it was not perfect. using your query I am not able to get all rows of questions table it is giving only those questions which have at least one answer but I need all questions doesnt matter answer is there or not.

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta I knew it, check my edited answer.

Comment: yes this time it is working, both queries are totally different :)

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta The first one is just a little modification based on you and the second one is the right logic for your question.

Comment: man one issue left in your updated query, when two answers have same no of rates then it is giving two records of answers

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta Then use `DISTINCT`, check the answer again please.

Comment: no not working same result

Comment: why you checking two times cat_id. it's complicated now. I tried something and this is also working till now, can you please check is it right ?  SELECT q.q_id as question_id,q.question, a.* from questions q left join (select t3.*,u.username from  (SELECT t1.*from answers t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT q_id, max(rate) AS rate FROM answers where  GROUP BY q_id) t2 ON t1.q_id = t2.q_id AND t1.rate = t2.rate group by t1.q_id) t3 JOIN users u ON t3.user_id = u.user_id ) a on a.q_id=q.q_id where q.cat_id='8'